# Как подменить IP сервера в запросах puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, headless

Имеется какой либо сайт и `puppeteer`.

Как перехватить определенные запросы? И сделать тоже самое, что делает файл `hosts` в операционных системах, т.е. перенаправить запрос на  другой сервер без модификаций его параметров.

Я пробовал что-то вроде такого, но не получилось:

```js
let puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
puppeteer.launch({headless: false}).then(async(browser) => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const ip = '192.168.100.110';
    await page.setRequestInterception(true).then(async() => {
        await page.setRequestInterception(true);

        page.on('request', async (request) => {
            const url = new URL(request.url());
            if (request.url().includes('sub.example.org')) {
                request.continue({
                  url: `http://${ip}${url.pathname}`,
                  headers: {
                      'Host': url.host //Вызывает ошибку
                  }
                });
            } else {
            request.continue();}
        });


        await page.goto('https://sub.example.org', {
            timeout: 0,
            waitUntil: ['networkidle0','load']
        });
    });
})
```

---

UPD: код обновлен, но есть проблемы с исключением `net::ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT` при попытке замены хоста.

Comment: а что получилось в результате?

Comment: Да в прицнипе просто не грузило, а c hosts работало, сейчас понизил версию пакета и чуть переделал, вроде что то работает, правда Host походу подменить не так то просто будет, там какие то с этим проблемы, `net::ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT` сыплется. Я же ведь правильно делаю «редирект»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// @ts-check
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: [
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-web-security'
    ]
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  page.on('request', (request) => {
    if (request.url().includes('cs.pikabu.ru')) {
      const url = new URL(request.url());
      url.protocol = 'http';
      url.host = '5.187.0.220';

      request.continue({
        url: url.toString(),
        headers: {
          referer: 'cs.pikabu.ru',
        }
      });
    } else {
      request.continue();
    }
  });


  await page.goto('https://pikabu.ru', {
    timeout: 0,
    waitUntil: ['networkidle0', 'load']
  });

})();
```